# From DOMDocument to CURL?

Tags: php

im using DOMDocuments to download an RSS feed into my PHP script, simple by:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($source);
```

I want to use instead of DOMDocument, CURL. How can change those 2 lines of code to make all my script compatible?. This is my complete script by the way:

```
<?php
//PUBLIC VARS
$arrFeeds = array();
$downItems = 0;
$time_taken = 0;
//*PUBLIC VARS
function getRSS($source) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);
    global $arrFeeds, $downItems, $time_taken;
    $arrFeeds = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($source);
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $itemRSS = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
        array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
        $downItems+=1;
    }
    $time_taken = microtime(true) - $start;
}
//getRSS("http://www.atm-mi.it/_layouts/atm/apps/PublishingRSS.aspx?web=388a6572-890f-4e0f-a3c7-a3dd463f7252&c=News%20Infomobilita");
//echo(strip_tags($arrFeeds[0]['title'])."<br><br>".$time_taken);
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might consider using SimplePie, to save yourself a lot of headache:  http://simplepie.org/wiki/

Comment: Why do you want to use curl? Do you have curl installed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
$ch = curl_init($source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($content);
```

Your mileage may vary, of course, and you might have to [add more CURL options](http://php.net/curl-setopt), but that's basic enough functionality to get it all started.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\Domingo\Dropbox\www\temp\parser.php on line 12

Comment: you'll need to enable the CURL library then.  This will depend on your specific config, so if you want help from me I'll need to know what OS you're running and whether or not you can edit your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @DomingoSL: That error means, you don't have the curl extension. And if you don't have the curl extension you can not use it!

Comment: If all you want is to have the source content available, you could replace all the stuff from `$ch = curl_init($source);` to `curl_close($ch);` with `$content = @file_get_contents($source);` since you seem to have `allow_url_fopen` set to on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `loadXML`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php